# Processing large xml elements containing base64 encoded data using Simple Framework

Tags: android, xml, simple-framework

I'm reading and writing a large xml file in an Android application and struggling with memory issues. The size is due to multiple elements containing base64 encoded images. Without these BLOBs, the xml is consumable

So far I have mapped the structure to the Simple Framework and managed to read it, but before I do the load I am preprocessing the XML file using STAX to strip out the BLOBs and replace them with URIs.

Now I need to serialize the structure back to xml and I'm wondering if there is a way I can interrupt the processing of a particular element to directly write the **referenced** BLOB to the output stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways with Simple XML. Take a look at @Replace and another way is with @Persist and @Commit. There should be plenty of examples of these int he test case. However, for @Replace just think of the Java Serialization writeReplace().

Comment: Thanks, I went with <code>@Persist</code> and <code>@Complete</code>. Sadly my usecase is complicated by needing to ignore the annotations depending on the scenario, so I currently have a global boolean to check if the method should actually perform the logic :| Is it possible to pass in a strategy or something into the Persister to fine tune the behaviour?